# Como vejo horário q abri e fechei um app no celular Android?

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Instagram mostrou meu visto por último as 03h da manhã, mas meu último acesso foi as 01h, no Google vejo esse acesso as 01h, mas lá só mostra o horário q abre o app, n até q horas ficou nele. Segue a imagem do Google. Até encontrei um app que me dar essas informações, porém só a partir do dia que baixei o app, e a data da informação que quero é 30/12/2018. É importante, me ajudem por favor!

Comment: Gente, não sou da área de tecnologia, não entendo de nada. Só estou desesperada mesmo. :(

Comment: Mesmo assim o escopo desta comunidade não é fornecer suporte técnico, mas sim sobre programação e áreas afins. Você pode ler mais no [tour] e na [help] se tiver interesse.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

*Mesmo assim* não deixa de ser uma questão técnica.

Tem algumas possibilidades:

- **Fuso Horário**: O google pode estar levando em conta ou o seu próprio servidor, ou o servidor do Instagram.
- **Atividade autônoma**: O seu telefone mesmo em modo ocioso, pode-se conectar de tempos em tempos para verificar notificações.
- **Sessões Salvas**: Você efetuou login em outros dispositivos, pode ter deixado conectado. Aí sim, outras pessoas estariam usando.

  Sugiro que faça um teste: Entre em um horário específico (ie: 15:00hs) no seu horário local, e confira se o controle de atividade do Google marcou isso.

  Você pode olhar em **Detalhes** de cada item do histórico, para saber mais.

  *obs.: Em um celular as informações são resumidas, use um computador*:

  [image: Detalhes]

Comment: Oi, Luiz. Muito obrigada por estar tentando me ajudar. Quando entro em detalhes, o Google não dar essas informações (só apenas que horas acessei novamente, não até que horas continuo usando que era o que precisava), na verdade não tem nada demais lá. Será que no Android tem algum comando oculto com esses detalhes?

Comment: E pelo uso de bateria? Ja tentou ver? acredito que marque tanto tempo de uso

Comment: Como assim pelo uso de bateria?

Comment: Procurei, mas não encontrei como ver pelo uso da bateria.